# python recursively rename dictionary keys with function

Tags: python, dictionary, key, rename

I want to take a nested dictionary and rename all the keys from camelcase to snake_case.  I have the current code but it is not working.

```
def camel_to_snake(name):
    name = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', name).lower()

def alter_keys(dictionary, func):
    empty = {}
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            alter_keys(v, func)
        if isinstance(v, str):
            empty[func(k)] = dictionary.pop(k)
        
    return empty

x = alter_keys(random_nested_dict, camel_to_snake)
```

Answer (score 6):

From what I understand you're asking, I think there's two issues at play. Firstly, you can't change the size of a `dict` as you iterate through it (I don't see the purpose of the `dictionary.pop` as you're creating and returning a separate dict `empty`). Secondly, you need to use the return value in the recursive case to update `empty`, as the recursive call doesn't mutate `dictionary` itself with altered keys. Here's the modified code:

```
def camel_to_snake(name):
    name = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', name).lower()

def alter_keys(dictionary, func):
    empty = {}
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            empty[func(k)] = alter_keys(v, func)
        if isinstance(v, str):
            empty[func(k)] = v
    return empty
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work for embedded dictionaries . . . it only goes one level deep and then returns empty dictionaries for further levels

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following which seems to work properly for my needs, it is working for nested dictionaries with internal arrays (possibly other dictionaries) which is a standard scenario with Json. I used it to remap keys according to a map dictionary "oldname" -> "newname"

```
def map_key(key):
   if key in map:
      return map[key]
   else:
      return key

def replace_keys(dictionary: dict, fun) -> dict:
    empty = {}
    # special case when it is called for element of array being NOT a dictionary
    if type(dictionary) == str:
        # nothing to do
        return dictionary

    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if type(v) == dict:
            empty[fun(k)] = replace_keys(v, fun)

        elif type(v) == list:
            newvalues = [replace_keys(x, fun) for x in v]
            empty[fun(k)] = newvalues

        else:
            empty[fun(k)] = v
    return empty

ret1 = replace_keys(ret, map_key)
```